# Is it possible to add tickboxes in a DT datatable?

Tags: r, dt

I would like to ask if it is possible to add a column with tickboxes in a `DT` datatable. I tried to use `rep(TRUE,5)` which works for `rhandsontable` but not for `DT`.

```
library(DT)
datatable(
data.frame(Sel. = rep(TRUE,5),
           Label=paste("Test",as.integer(1:5)),
           Marg=rep(5),
           Avail.=as.integer(rep.int(5,5)),
           Sel =as.integer(rep.int(5,1)),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

We can use the `datatable` extension `Select` for that (see [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/integration/select-checkbox.html) for details).

Here is a minimal RMarkdown example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
datatable(
    iris %>% rowid_to_column("Row") %>% mutate(Row = ""),
    rownames = FALSE,
    extensions = "Select",
    options = list(
        columnDefs = list(list(className = "select-checkbox", targets = 0, orderable = FALSE)),
        select = list(style = "os", selector = "td:first-child")))
```
````

This produces

[image]

A few comments:

1. We load the `Select` extension through `extensions = "Select"`. See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html) for details on potential compatibility issues.
2. We add row numbers as a new column, and then set all row numbers to empty strings `""`; this is a bit hack-y, but if we leave row names (=row numbers) as they are they will show up *along-side* the checkboxes. I found creating a new empty column, and then setting `rownames = FALSE` ensures that we have only check-boxes in the empty column. `orderable = FALSE` in `columnDefs` then ensures that this column is not sortable.

Comment: That is an exceptional answer.Tnx

Comment: Thank you very much:-) and you're very welcome @firmo23!

Comment: Hey one small clarification..how can I select multiple rows at the same time? Right now I can only one.

Comment: @firmo23 If I want to select multiple items, I need to keep the command key pressed on my Mac. On a Windows machine it should be the control key I believe. Or use shift to select multiple adjacent items.

Comment: Cool!Tnx again!