# Display the number of rows of a datatable that are selected by tickboxes in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a simple shiny app.

```
#ui.r
navbarPage(
  "Application",
  tabPanel("General",
           sidebarLayout(

             sidebarPanel(
               uiOutput("tex2")

              ),
             mainPanel(
               DT::dataTableOutput("hot3")

             )
           )))
           #server.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$tex2<-renderUI({
    numericInput("text2","Rows selected",
                 value = 1,
                 min=1
    )
  })



  output$hot3 <-DT::renderDataTable(
    iris%>% rowid_to_column("Row") %>% mutate(Row = ""),
    rownames = FALSE,
    extensions = "Select",
    options = list(
      columnDefs = list(list(className = "select-checkbox", targets = 0, orderable = FALSE)),
      select = list(style = "os", selector = "td:first-child")),
    selection=list(mode="single")


  )

}
```

What I need to do is display the number of rows selected in the datatable in the `numericInput()` in the sidebarPanel. This number is already displayed under the table but I would like to have it in the `numericInput()` as well.  If I want to select multiple items, I need to keep the command key pressed on my Mac. On a Windows machine it should be the control key I believe. Or use shift to select multiple adjacent items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example using an RMarkdown document with a `shiny` backend to show how to get the number of selected rows.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
dataTableOutput("irisTable")
output$irisTable <- renderDataTable(
    iris %>% rowid_to_column("Row") %>% mutate(Row = ""),
    rownames = FALSE,
    extensions = "Select",
    options = list(
        columnDefs = list(list(className = "select-checkbox", targets = 0, orderable = FALSE)),
        select = list(style = "multi", selector = "td:first-child")
        ))

p("Selected rows are...")
renderText(input$irisTable_rows_selected)
```
````

[image]

Please note that in comparison to my answer to [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275605/is-it-possible-to-add-tickboxes-in-a-dt-datatable), I've changed the `select.style` behaviour to `select = list(style = "multi", selector = "td:first-child")`; this allows you to select multiple entries by single-clicking on rows (instead of having to hold the Command/Ctrl key).

Comment: It works but something strange happens. While I can select multiple rows the rows are not highlighted at the same time except the last one.

Comment: @firmo23 Did you change from `style = "os"` to `style = "multi"` like in my example? I found some inconsistent behaviour with `style = "os"`.

Comment: yes I did. It ts strange but not critical so thank you I will accept the answer! Btw is it possible to have 1 row selected by default?

Comment: No need fot that. The highlight issue remains but thanks a lot.

Comment: @firmo23 Ok. The highlight issue seems to be OS dependent. With `style = "multi"` I select/deselect individual rows with a single click, and the number of selected rows gets updated accordingly. With `style = "os"` when I single-click individual rows, only one row stays highlighted at the same time, but the returned number of selected rows indicates that previously clicked rows are still selected. Until I click them again twice. Strange.